# Getting the value of a constant

Tags: java

I have a Java EE project in which I have many calls to function which is receiving a string and this string is stored in a constant which is not necessarily defined in the same file, it is sometimes defined in a separate constants class. I need to go over all the classes in the project and retrieve the values of those constants. What would be smart way to do this? 
I thought about using reflection and load every class in the project (a few hundreds), but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the string stored in one constant, or multiple?

Comment: Every string is stored in one constant

Comment: and this function you just want one of those strings, right?

Comment: why do you need to retrieve all the constants values?

Comment: No, I want to generate a list of all the values of the strings that are passed to this function

Comment: so you want a list of all the string parameters for the function (e.g: void dothis (string str1, string str2) => List<string> params = {str1, str2}?

Comment: Do you need to get all the possible constant values at runtime? What do you plan to do with the values?

Comment: @davidmontoyago The value is a name of a class, and due to changes in a framework we're using, those classes will undergo some changes as well, so it's for singling them out

Comment: So, do you know all the names of the constants you need or the constant has the same name in all the classes?

Comment: if all constants are in a constants class, then get it directly from there... just like pi is in a class...

Comment: I know all the names of the constants since they are being passed to the function (and they have different names)

Comment: you could directly load all the constants and add them to a list

Answer (score 0):

since you know all the names of the constants and they are in one class (the constants class), I'd recommend just using that class. You do not need to go through every other class if the constants are all in one class.

what you could do is set the parameters equal to the constant name and use reflection to look in the constants class (and only that class) to get the values of all the constants that have names that match the parameters.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about it, but there is more than one constants class and the constant is not always defined in a constant class. The idea is I can't tell where the constant is defined (the programmers did not follow a convention while writing the project)

Comment: in that scenario you have 3 choices. you can either refactor it so that all the constants are in one class; you could use ctrl + f to find all constants and move them into one class and refactor accordingly. the disdvantage is that this may take quite some time. if you do this, i'd backup the project first.

you could also use ctrl + f to find the class the constant is directly defined in, and load it from there. be aware that if you change it's location, you'll have to change all references. 

finally, you could just bite the bullet and use reflection. is time consuming, but no ref-changing.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to go over all the classes in the project and retrieve the values of those constants.

It is highly unlikely you need to do this. A String you create will be `equals()` to an existing constant and you shouldn't assume it has to be the same object. You shouldn’t be using `==` for Strings as this is bad practice.

But to answer you question literally, you can call `String.intern()` this will give you a String reference of any existing String constant. (Or the same reference if it is not yet defined as such)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand, but based on the fact that you know where the constants are and its names, you can import all the constants classes statically and do whatever you want with the values:

```
public class Constants1 {
    public static final String A = "A";
    public static final String B = "B";
}
public class Constants12 {
    public static final String C = "C";
}
```

Import your constants:

```
import static constants.Constants1.*;
import static constants.Constants2.*;

public class ConstantsProcessor {

    static String[] constants = {A,B,C};

}
```